Are these plushies of inanimate objects haram to have as an adult?
Assalamualaikum!
I was wondering if the following are haram. I know it's clear animals and humans are haram, but what about things like boba with incomplete features? As you see it only has eyes and lips, no nose, that would make it incomplete which would not be haram? Or would it be? 
